# Get int from boost::variant generate segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, get, int, boost-variant

I am trying to get int value from boost::variant. Code generate segmentation fault - why?
I put comments in code which lines generate error. I supposed that

```
int numberInt = boost::get<int>(v);
```

will not working correctly so I changed it to

```
int *ptrInt = boost::get<int>(&v);
```

which is compiling but still I am not managed to get int value? Exactly the same is with double. String type is working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <boost/variant/get.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boost::variant<int, double, std::string> v;
  v = 16;
  v = 3.1415;
  v = "hello new year";

  //int numberInt = boost::get<int>(v);     //1) not working
  //double numberDouble = boost::get<double>(v);//2) not working

  int *ptrInt = boost::get<int>(&v);        //3) compiling
  if(ptrInt) 
    cout << *ptrInt << endl;            //4) not displayed
  //cout << *ptrInt << endl;            //5) segmentation fault

  double *ptrDouble = boost::get<double>(&v);   //6) compiling
  if(ptrDouble) 
    cout << *ptrDouble << endl;         //7) not displayed
  //cout << *ptrDouble << endl;         //8) segmentation fault

  std::string caption = boost::get<string>(v);
  cout << caption << endl;          //9) working

  return 0;
}

// clear && clear && g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test && ./test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what boost variant is. The documentation of the library describes the `variant` type as "multi-type, **single value**." (emphasis mine). Since you've assigned a value of type `std::string`, no other types of value is stored in the `variant`. A nice thing about `variant` (when compared to `union`) is described in the comments of the `get` function:

```
// Retrieves content of given variant object if content is of type T.
// Otherwise: pointer ver. returns 0; reference ver. throws bad_get.
```

So, if `int numberInt = boost::get<int>(v);` *works correctly*, it should throw an exception. And `int *ptrInt = boost::get<int>(&v);` should return a null pointer. Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour and likely the cause for your segmentation faults.

I think the behaviour that you're looking for is in `tuple` (found in both boost and std). A simple struct/class would work too if you don't mind giving a name for the member objects.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you did not understand how `boost::variant` worked. In type theory, a `boost::variant` is a Sum Type, or [`Algebraic Data Type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

This is also often called "discriminated union" and basically looks like (in this case):

```
struct Variant {
    size_t index;
    union {
        int a;
        double b;
        std::string c;
    } u;
};
```

Now, when you write `v = 16` what happens is:

```
v.u.a = 16; v.index = 0;
```

When you then write `v = 3.1415` what happens is:

```
v.u.b = 3.1415; v.index = 1;
```

And finally when you write `v = "hello new year"` what happens is:

```
v.u.c = "hello new year"; v.index = 2;
```

Note that, each time, the `index` representing which member of the `union` is currently active is updated... and therefore **only a single member of the union is active at any point in time**.

When you use `boost::get<int>(&v)` the code actually looks like:

```
int* get_0(Variant* v) {
    if (v && v->index == 0) { return &v->u.a; }
    return nullptr;
}
```

and therefore, since at this point `v->index` is `2`, it returns a `nullptr`.

The only `get` that will work is `boost::get<std::string>(&v)` because it checks whether the `index` is `2`, which it is, and therefore returns a pointer to `v.u.c`.